# How to use batching, something like BeginUpdate/EndUpdate, when doing bulk change in ViewModel in MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

In my Silverlight application which uses MVVM, I have a chart(3rd party ComponentOne) which plots huge data hence takes good amount of time to render.

I have an ObservableCollection(say chartDataCollection), in my ViewModel, which is bind to data source of chart.

In some of the scenarios, I add 100s of items in chartDataCollection which leads to CollectionChange event being fired 100s times and renders the chart every time which takes lots of time.

**Is there anyway in C# by which I can group together these update and notify to UI only once when I am done?** Something like we used to in Winforms world while adding data to datagrid using BeginUpdate and EndUpdate statements.

Comment: It would be great is they added an `AddRange()` to the ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface to implement is INotifyCollectionChanged. This interface communicates with WPF binding via the CollectionChanged event - the argument to this event (NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) can report batches of items that has been changed.

One way to do it would be to implement your own MyBatchObservableColleciton, deriving or (better) embedding List (or any other appropriate collection). Implement methods to modify the innter collection and record all these changes. When you are ready to commit all your changes to WPF, just send the list of changes. Here is a subset example of what you would may do (implementing only 'Add' funcitonality to your collection):

```
class BatchObservableColleciton<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    private List<T> _list;
    private List<T> _addedItems;

    public BatchObservableColleciton( ) {
        _list = new List<T>( );
        _addedItems = new List<T>( );
    }
    
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator( )
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator( );
    }

    public void Add( T item )
    {
        _list.Add( item );
        _addedItems.Add( item );
    }

    public void Commit( ) {
        if( CollectionChanged != null ) {
            CollectionChanged( this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, _addedItems ) );
        }
        _addedItems.Clear( );
    }

}
```

Never tried it myself, but I think this is the way to go. Google for Custom & ObservableCollection. Although not exact, there are few implementations out there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `ObservableCollection`, use a simple `IEnumerable` property utilizing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern.

```
private IEnumerable _ChartDataCollection;
public IEnumerable ChartDataCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _ChartDataCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_ChartDataCollection != value)
        {
            _ChartDataCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ChartDataCollection");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer. In addition to IEnumerable, you must implement INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: No, it'll work, just you'll have to reset the whole ChartDataCollection property on each add/remove to the chart datasource

Comment: @Uri INotifyCollectionChanged presents the problem the OP is having. While your solution works, it is over-architechted. My solution works, and is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a separate collection for all the changes, then merge the two collections and assign it to your public collection once you're finished? This will only fire the `PropertyChanged` event once.

```
// Create a new List that contains objects from your Collection
var list = new List<SomeItem>(SomeCollection);

foreach(var item in newItems)
{
    // Add new items to list
}

// Reset collection w/ items from List
SomeCollection = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>(list);
```

Comment: You don't want to overwrite the SomeCollection, because the UI is bound to the existing instance. So you won't see any update.